# Try to understand "Class and instance variable annotations" in PEP 526

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

It seems to me that I misunderstand the [PEP 526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) in the context of annotating class and instance variables.

Based on the example in the PEP document here the object `bar` should be an *instance variable* with default value `7`:

```
class Foo:
    bar: int = 7
    
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
```

But testing that with Python it seems different to me. `bar` is an class and instance variable.

```
Python 3.9.10 (tags/v3.9.10:f2f3f53, Jan 17 2022, 15:14:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo:
...   bar: int = 7
...   def __init__(self, bar):
...     self.bar = bar
...
>>> Foo.bar
7
>>> f = Foo(3)
>>> f.bar
3
>>> f.__class__.bar
7
>>>
```

Maybe the PEP is not only clear about it? IMHO the PEP is violated and the goal not reached.

Comment: `Foo.bar` is a _class attribute_ that is then shadowed by `self.bar` the _instance attribute_ of `f`. If you want a default that's _not_ a class attribute it could be in the parameter list, `def __init__(self, bar=7):`.

Comment: _"the PEP is violated and the goal not reached"_ - what exactly do you mean by this? What's your goal?

Comment: I know that. But that is IMHO not what the PEP tries to tell us. In the PEP example there is the variable `captain` which is described as an instance variable only. But it isn't.

Comment: No, it describes it as _"an instance variable with a default value set in the class"_, as distinct in that example from _"truly a class variable"_. It also refers specifically to _"the value-less notation"_ for instance attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no conflict, and the PEP does explain what is going on.

First of all: An instance variable is just a name set on an instance (usually via `self.[name] = ...`), and class variables are just names set on a class (usually by assigning to a name within the `class ...` statement body. **They are not mutually exclusive**.

What you may be missing is how Python looks up names on instances. When you have an instance `foo` and you want to get attribute `bar`, then `foo.bar` is actually handled by code defined for the class, as it needs to make a few checks for more advanced use-cases (called *descriptors*), but in the case of regular variables it’ll return the value from an instance variable before falling back to the class variable. **This is how default values work**; if there is no `bar` set on the instance then the value from the class is used.

In other words: a default value for an instance variable set on the class only comes into play when you *don’t* set an a value on the instance:

```py
>>> class Foo:
...     bar: int = 7
...     def __init__(self, bar: int | None):
...         if bar is not None:
...             self.bar = bar
...
>>> f1 = Foo()  # default value for bar
>>> f2 = Foo(3)  # explicit value set
>>> Foo.bar  # default on class
7
>>> f1.bar   # is returned here
7
>>> "bar" in vars(f1)  # as there is no instance variable
False
>>> f2.bar  # gets the instance value
3
>>> vars(f2)["bar"]  # from the instance namespace
3
```

The [section you link to](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) talks about why there is a need to *annotate* class variables **for type checkers**. The example they give has two names, one *intended* to be a default value for an instance attribute and the other *intended* to be only set on the class. Without that type annotation the type checker can’t distinguish between those two cases because they look exactly the same otherwise:

```py
class Starship:
    captain = 'Picard'
    stats = {}
```

The `stats` dict is meant to be shared between instances, so `self.stats = ...` would shadow the class variable and break the intended use:

> `stats` is intended to be a class variable (keeping track of many different per-game statistics), while `captain` is an instance variable with a default value set in the class. This difference might not be seen by a type checker: both get initialized in the class, but `captain` serves only as a convenient default value for the instance variable, while `stats` is truly a class variable – it is intended to be shared by all instances.

Using `ClassVar[...]` lets a type checker know that creating an instance attribute should be an error, while assigning to `self.captain` is not:

> Since both variables happen to be initialized at the class level, it is useful to distinguish them by marking class variables as annotated with types wrapped in `ClassVar[...]`. **In this way a type checker may flag accidental assignments to attributes with the same name on instances.**

Note that the purpose of the PEP is to define how *type annotations* work for variables, including class and instance variables, *not* define how Python variables work at runtime! Type annotations are designed to be machine readable documentation for static analysis tools, and are there to help find programmer errors. Don’t try to read this as a description of how the Python *runtime* works.